# Regular expression for [a-zA-Z]

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have a regular expression that matches English letters only, a `[a-zA-Z]` character class.

Is there any built-in regular expression for that? I mean something like `\s` or `\w`.

Comment: Why can't you use `[a-zA-Z]`?

Comment: [\[\[:alpha:\]\]](https://regex101.com/r/vD8yQ0/1)

Comment: I will explain my question abd i will ask you to forgive my terrible English. I am building an engine to recognize regular expressions in assembly (8086) for school project. And i want to know if there is any shortcut for the only the letters a-z and A-Z with no other letters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking for a [shorthand class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for English letters.

In case you are using [POSIX-compliant regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), `[:alpha:]` is the "bracket expression" for `[a-zA-Z]` class. It is also supported by PCRE (Perl, PHP, Ruby...).

In [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), you can use `\p{Alpha}`.

In [.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories), [PCRE](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt), [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `\p{L}` is more than just `[a-zA-Z]` as it might include all Unicode letters. Still, it can be used to capture only letters.