# Extract characters up to "/" using R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract characters before and after the "/" character using R.

For example, I can get the tags with the following:

```
s <- "hello/JJ world/NN"

# get the tags
sapply(s, function(x){gsub("([a-z].*?)/([A-z].*?)", "\\2", x)})
```

which returns

```
"JJ NN"
```

However, when I try to extract the characters before the "/" or the "tokens", using the following:

```
sapply(s, function(x){gsub("([a-z].*?)/([A-z].*?)", "\\1", x)})
```

I get

```
"helloJ worldN"
```

How can I get "hello world" and why is the first letter of the tag slipping in there?

Comment: you're using sapply on a vector of length one. why not just `gsub('/[a-z]+', '', s, ignore.case = TRUE)` and `gsub('[a-z]+/', '', s, ignore.case = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Try `gsub('/\\w+', '', s)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason you get those letters remaining in the output is your regex. The `[A-Z]` (there must be `Z`, I guess `z` is a typo - see [[A-Za-z] Shorthand class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110807/regular-expression-for-a-za-z/30111199#30111199)) is OK, but it is followed by a `.*?` lazy dot matching group that can match 0 or unlimited characters other than newline *as few as possible*. So, it [will match none](https://regex101.com/r/nL3uC6/2).

You need a `+` quantifier to match 1 or more characters and apply it to the character class `[a-zA-Z]`:

```
s <- "hello/JJ world/NN"
sapply(s, function(x){gsub("([a-zA-Z])/[a-zA-Z]+", "\\1", x)})
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/C2dDN4)

I removed the second group since you are not using it.

Comment: or you could just copy/paste the output below the code?